# How to filter blocked words from a query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table called "Keywords" containing a list of Keywords (may be a phrase or a single word), its columns are: ID, Keyword.

There is also another table called "Blocked" containing a list of words (single word, not a phrase) which should be used to filter the "Keywords" table. It's columns are: ID, Word.

I would like to know a quick way or an optimized method to filter the keywords from "Keywords" table with all the words listed in "Blocked" table.

For example, in "Keywords" table, I have this list:

> ## 1 - Friends in Facebook
>
> ## 2 - Blogging with Facebook
>
> ## 3 - Finding Friends
>
> ## 4 - Doing something to Friends in Facebook
>
> ## 5 - Programming is Fun

Here's my list as well in the "Blocked" table:

> ## 1 - play
>
> ## 2 - friend
>
> ## 3 - find

Whenever I fetch the keywords from the "Keywords" table, it should be filtered with the words listed in "Blocked" table. Therefore in these lists, if I fetch data from "Keywords" table, I should get these results:

> ## 2 - Blogging with Facebook
>
> ## 5 - Programming is Fun

Notice that #1 isn't included since it contains the word "friend" (which is listed in the "Blocked" table). #3 isn't included as well since it contains "find". Finally, #4 isn't included since it also contains "friend".

My biggest problem is what kind of method to use in order to achieve this. Take note that I have a large amount of keywords (about 10 million records) and at least 100 blocked words. I have developed a PHP+MySQL solution for this, but it's reaaaaally really slow.

Hope you can give me your solution or suggestion.

Comment: Probably better off showing us your solution and asking what is slow about it, than this behemoth

Comment: Have you got indexing on the tables? This will dramatically improve the table performance...

Answer (score 1):

If you want performance, you should forget about trying to filter a big table like that.

You should create another table with whitelisted words, that is generated upon adding/removing/editing a blacklisted word, and use that table on queries that need this filter. The overhead wiill just exist when you update this table upon the events that may add/remove backlisted keywords.

This way you will avoid:

- Subqueries with NOT IN
- Big loops or array_map/filter functions

Remember that today you have 100 keywords, but tomorrow you can have 1000, and using any other method than pre-filtering results on a new table will bring a performance loss and will always enlarge the gap between what you´re looking for.

Comment: `NOT IN` could be fast with proper indices. `NOT IN` with a `LIKE '%keyword%'` subquery will be the real killer.

Comment: Here is an interesting test on the subject : http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/